# WebBrowser control not showing last 2 lines of local HTML file

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a WebBrowser control that's loaded with a local HTML file, like so:

```
var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("View/Help.html", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rs.Stream);
browser.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
```

It displays fine, except the last two lines are cropped off.  It's like the viewport of the WebBrowser isn't large enough (I can pull up and see the last two lines, but when I let go it bounces back down).  The HTML file is fairly long, maybe 5 screens worth.

The XAML for the page is super simple, the entire page is the WebBrowser control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Width="480" Height="800" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got the `ApplicationBar` visible then you'll need to reduce the size of your `WebBrowser` otherwise you'll be displaying content underneath the app bar.

Comment: Yup that was it (and the `SystemTray` too).  Setting `browser.Height = this.ActualHeight` in the `Loaded` event seemed to work.